# How to find reference of an Activity from a library and close(finish()) the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, shared-libraries

Scenario :

An activity is displayed. It has a text box and a button. If you enter a special code in the textbox and click the button the activity closes after comparing the text logic. Simple! This has been implemented in the OnCLick() of the the activity.

Problem :

I have a library that handles all the the SMS receiver functionalities. The receiver remotely listens for a special incoming SMS. Once the special sms arrives, a library function (closeActivity) should either

1. finish() the activity(described above) straightaway
2. imitate the action of entering text + clicking button by getting a reference to the activity somehow?

I am fine with either. which ever is simpler and safer!

I just need to know how/where/what code to write in the library so that it can finish() the activity!

Assumption: The activity is always displayed and the system is not stacking it automatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try to use intents? esp broadcast intents.. Fire the broadcast intent from library and get it in ur activity /another class registered as intent reciever . You can get the instance of activity in the broadcast reciever easily.

`public static <Your activity class> activitySingleTon`

and set the singleton in appropriate lifecycle method.

`OnCreate(){ activitySingleTon = this; }`

and use in broadcast reciever like this

`if(<your activity class>.activitySingleTon)`

`{ <your activity class>.activitySingleTon.finish(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Can there be several instances of the Activity?
If not, make it a singleton, then reference it from anywhere with MyActivity.getInstance().

Best regards.

Comment: Thnx. I am googling how to declare an activity a singleton. Did come across a few posts saying singleton might not be a good idea..but the reference of discussions were different. Would understand the concept better once I get to know a little more about singleton activities!